# How to auto update chromedriver in webdriverIO

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I have an automation framework developed using webdriverIO. The issue is all test cases start failing whenever chrome updated as chromedriver didn't update automatically.

This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 92

is there any way that ChromeDriver  updated automatically whenever there is new available

Comment: The Chrome version might also need to be set in wdio.conf.ts as well if using @wdio/selenium-standalone-service: https://webdriver.io/docs/selenium-standalone-service/

Answer (score 0):

Please note down latest version of Chrome (Help > About Google Chrome )

then check your package.json file where we have line like

"chromedriver": "^98.0.0",

update above line with latest chrome version like
"chromedriver": "^100.0.0",

then run command
npm install

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands this will auto-update all the JSON dependencies to the latest version
To update to the latest version
npx npm-check-updates -u

Answer (score 0):

`npm install` and `npm install chromedriver --save-dev`